# Bootstrap modal doesn't remain fixed when scrolling

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, scroll, popup, modal-dialog, fixed

I'm using snap.js on my site and on one page, a Bootstrap modal which has a fixed position by default. However, I believe as this modal is in the .snap-content container which has absolute positioning, the modal doesn't remain fixed and scrolls with the rest of the page. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you show some code?

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem.

The solution I came up is modifying the snap.css

```
.snap-content {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: auto;
 height: auto;
 z-index: 2;
 overflow: auto;
 -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
 /*-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);*/
 /*-moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);*/
 /*-ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);*/
 /*-o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);*/
 /*transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);*/
}
```

I still don't know why this alters the behavior of the modal but so far it works with no problems with the snap drawers either